# I need to retrieve data from two different table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two different tables, answers table and question table, i need to get  question ID and answer selected by a user which i have managed to retrieve, my problem is from the same form view i need to retrieve the correct answer and the point that i created in question table.From my view the first two column are retrieved from answers table, therefore i need the second two column from question table to be retrieved
 please anyone who can help me, below is how i have tried to do

Here is my view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Question No</th>
        <th scope="col">Answer</th>
        <th scope="col">Correct Answer</th>
        <th scope="col">Marks</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($results as  $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$i++}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->question_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->answer}}
            <td>{{$data->qns_ans}}
            <td>{{$data->qns_point}}
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $results = Answers::all();
    $qns = Questions::all();

    return view('test.result')
        ->with('results', $results)
        ->with('qns', $qns);
}
```

Comment: You did not specify your problem. If you created the tables you can use either Laravel Eloquent or the DB query builder to access and execute database related queries. Please see Laravel docs e.g. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: i have edited the question to make it clear

Comment: can you share question and answer Models, please?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make relation `one to many` between questions and answers

check first that answers table has `question_id` column

then add this method to your Question Model to make relation

```
function answers(){
  return $this->hasMany(\App\Answer::class);
}
```

So now you can easily from an instance of Question Model say that

```
$question = Question::first()->get();
dd($question->answer);
```

you will see now when you dump it, it will give you the answers that belongs to this question

Comment: my model has relation i only need the concept on how i get the data of the second table to be displayed in the same view , the first two column are from answer table and the third and fourth column are from question table

Comment: if you had already prepared relation before so you can write it like this 
`$data->answers->qns_ans`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did to query my two tables data

```
          This is my controller 
            public function index()
            {

            $results=Answers::all();
            $qns = Questions::all();

                 return view('test.result')->with('results',$results)
                             ->with('qns',$qns);
                 }
```

This is my view

```
                  <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                           <th>S/N</th>
                         <th scope="col">Question No</th>
                         <th scope="col">Answer</th>
                          <th scope="col">Correct Answer</th>
                           <th scope="col">Marks</th>

                             </tr>
                           </thead>
                           <tbody>
                               <?php $i=1; ?>
                                @foreach($results as  $data)
                             <tr>

                                 <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                                 <td>{{$data->question_id}}</td>
                                 <td>{{$data->answer}} </td>
                                 <td>{{$data->question['ans']}} </td>
                                 <td>{{$data->question['point']}} 

                              </tr>
                                  @endforeach
                                     </tbody>
                                 </table>

                      Here is my model
                     class Answers extends Model

                       {
                       protected $fillable = ['question_id','answer'];


                          public function question(){
                          return $this->belongsTo(Questions::class); 
                          }
                          }


                   class Questions extends Model
                            {
                         protected $fillable = 
                         ['question_name','opt1','opt2','opt3',
                          'opt4','ans','point'];

                          public function answer(){
                          return $this->hasOne(Answer::class); 
                          }

                          }
```